# Convergence of iterated distribution function.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convergence-divergence

Let $F(x)$ be a cumulative distribution function. Does iterative function $F^{(k)}(x)=F(F^{(k-1)}(x)), F^{(1)}(x)=F(x)$ always converges as $k$ tends to infinity?

Comment: If the distribution in question is supported on $[2,3]$, for example, then the composition of $F$ with itself doesn't even make sense (the range of $F$ is always $[0,1]$ up to the endpoints).

Comment: @GregMartin Distribution functions are defined at all points. So the definition does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If $F(x) \geq x$ then $F^{(k+1)}(x)\geq  F^{(k)}(x)$ for all $k$ so $(F^{(k)}(x))$ is bounded increasing sequence. If $F(x) \leq x$ then $F^{(k+1)}(x)\leq  F^{(k)}(x)$ for all $k$ so $(F^{(k)}(x))$ is bounded decreasing  sequence. Hence  $ \lim F^{(k)}(x)$ exists for all $x$.